# Drupal 7 Forum with these features

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to setup a forum using Drupal 7 with these features:

- Manage user roles and give or revoke access to forums or topic per user.
- Create moderators where they can add,edit, delete members and forums,topics,posts
- Be able to get email notifications for every action made in the forums
- Be able to upload photos,docs etc

Could you tell which modules I need to make a forum like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How were you able to restrict the access? I'm looking to restrict certain forums or forum containers to certain roles, while allowing access to other forms to everyone. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the Advanced Forum and the Forum access modules I can have all the features I want.

Comment: How did you achieve the first point you have listed?
Manage user roles and give or revoke access to **forums or topic per user**.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the forum module that comes with Drupal core or you can integrate a phpBB installation. Check this module: [phpBBforum Integration module](http://drupal.org/project/phpbbforum). phpBB 3 is the best open source bulletin board. It is fast, secure and has a lot of features and extensions (mods). All the features that you need above are supported by phpBB 3.